# Why in Picasso.with(context), Picasso asks for context?

Tags: android, picasso

In the `Picasso.with(context)` ..

```
public static Picasso with(Context context) {
  if (singleton == null) {
    synchronized (Picasso.class) {
      if (singleton == null) {
        singleton = new Builder(context).build();
      }
    }
  }
  return singleton;
}
```

And the Builder(Context context) like this

```
/** Start building a new {@link Picasso} instance. */
public Builder(Context context) {
  if (context == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Context must not be null.");
  }
  this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
}
```

Why is Picasso even asking for a context when it is always `setting context = context.getApplicationContext( )` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already posted your answer -

```
public Builder(Context context) {
  if (context == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Context must not be null.");
  }
  this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
}
```

Picasso is a library and not an application. While creating Picasso  instance if you'll not pass `context`, then how do you think it will get the `application context` from ?
 For it to work it requires `context` , and it definitely needs to be provided by the application using this library.

Comment: It also prevents leaking an `Activity` (if that's what you pass) by switching to the application context.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JakeWharton for the clarity!

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to pass context after creating picasso instance with the help of builder

```
    // create Picasso.Builder object
    Picasso.Builder picassoBuilder = new Picasso.Builder(context);

    // Picasso.Builder creates the Picasso object to do the actual requests
    Picasso picasso = picassoBuilder.build(); 

    // instead of Picasso.with(Context context) you directly use this new custom Picasso object

picasso  
    .load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[0])
    .into(imageView1);
```

For more information you can read more about it here :-

https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-customizing-picasso-with-picasso-builder